# Is there any way to render from nodejs server into a chrome extension popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension, handlebars.js

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Music Player",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {"128": "icon_128.png"},
  "description": "Plays music in background of the web-browser",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": //"popup.html" works but not "https://localhost:5500/popup.html" 
  },
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

I have made a music player that takes in a youtube-playlist as input and plays it, problem here is that I am not able to render the page inside the Chrome Extension popup but if I try to do the same with a static html page it works.

My current approach is to render everything via server. If you have any suggestions please let me know. It is a college project where we are bound to use jQuery AJAX for now.

Another way could be to have a static HTML but send Form data via AJAX but I have no idea of how to send data and receive data. My backend(nodeJS) basically takes the Youtube Playlist URL and using handlebars it renders the title, thumbnail, songfileurl and the artist names in place!

Willing to go any level of complexity, please help.

Comment: Simply use `<iframe>` in popup.html and point its `src` to your localhost url.

Comment: BRO BRO BRO U MADE MY DAY !!!!!